# Use xinetd to make a script telnetable

Tags: linux, bash, script, xinetd

I have a script, which has to be run via

```
telnet localhost port
```

I have a script (`USER.sh`), and configured `/etc/xinetd.d/user`.

But whenever I connect, I get an error message saying:

```
TERM environment variable not set.
```

So I tried to add the following line to the script:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

But that didn't work either.

Attempt Nr 2:

My `/etc/xinetd.d/xxxx` file:

```
service xxxx
{
disable = no
socket_type = stream
protocol = tcp
port = 4502
type = UNLISTED
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/xxxx.sh
server_args = askme
}
```

My changed file:

```
service xxxx
{
disable = no
env = xterm-256color
socket_type = stream
protocol = tcp
port = 4502
type = UNLISTED
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/xxxx.sh
server_args = askme
}
```

But when I try to telnet, it gives me a connection refused Error… :/

I have even tried to make `test.sh`, which is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TERM=xterm-256color
telnet localhost 4502
```

But that does not seem to work either.

When I

```
echo $TERM
```

from a shell, it gives me:

```
xterm-256color
```

I am using Kali Linux 2016.1.

PS: It also won't show me the echo outputs of my script…

Comment: What does your script run?

Comment: It's a script to create a user, and automatically generates a password for him